# Auto downloads for sdcard/astrid

Tags: astrid

I have suddenly started getting lots of downloads from sdcard/Astrid/auto.
They are adverts. 
How do I switch them off ?

Comment: That is probably from some app/game that show ads so it has to store it somewhere

Comment: I'm really interested in helping you track this down. I work on a fork of Astrid called Tasks and I've had a few users complain that my app was showing advertisements (it doesn't have ads).

Answer (score 0):

Download a [terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yarolegovich.materialterminal).
In that terminal type `cd /sdcard/Astrid/`
Then run the command `chmod 000 auto`

That should do it!